# Load child swf with flashvars from parent swf

Tags: flash, flashvars

I have to load another swf from my swf and I need to give them flashvars attributes, how can I do that?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest(url+"id=33"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a question mark?

`loader.load(new URLRequest(url+"?id=33"));`

Comment: no i missed here only, typed badly. But i looked up, this pattern never will result flashvars...

Comment: Please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407858/passing-flashvars-style-parameters-to-a-loaded-swf