# AS3 Pass FlashVars to loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flashvars

I have a A.swf which loads B.swf onto a movieclip and needs to pass it some FlashVars. When loading B.swf with html, I can pass FlashVars fine. When passing from A.swf, it gets a

Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:

The code in A.swf is

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("B.swf");

var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.xml = "test.xml";

// This line causes the error 2044, else B.swf loads fine with FlashVars  
request.data = variables;

loader.load (request);
```

In B.swf, it is checking the Flashvars like so. It works fine from html side

```
this.loaderInfo.parameters.xml
```

Comment: It's an ambiguous question.  There are two parts:  
1) How to get FlashVars into B, which I answer below.
2) How to pass any kind of variables into B from A.

Answer (score 17):

Although the querystring method should work fine locally, if you're using Flash Player 10.2, there's a new API for this.

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.parameters = {'xml': 'test.xml'};
loader.load(request, context);
```

The documentation is here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#parameters

Comment: Seems to be removed from the API. `parameters` is undefined :(

Comment: @Sean: my bad, targeting 10.1. sorry

Comment: Didn't work for me as querystring (even in 10.2), but worked great when using LoaderContext in 10.2 -- +1

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary that "A" pass FlashVars to "B". Just have B access the FlashVars itself.  The following will work whether B is inside of A, or top-level itself:

Add an ADDED_TO_STAGE event listener in B's constructor.  e.g.:

```
function B(){
    this.addEventListener(Event.AddedToStage, onAddedToStageHandler);
}
```

When you have access to the stage you can now access the FlashVars in A this way:

To properly see a variable called `myVar` flashVar in B.swf, you do (inside B):

```
private function onAddedToStageHandler(){
var flashVars : Object = LoaderInfo(this.stage.loaderInfo).parameters;
// now you have access to your flashVars!
trace(flashVars.myVar);
}
```

`stage.loaderInfo` is what you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the flash vars into the URI when you are loading it

```
URLRequest(String("B.swf" + "?myvar=45"));
```

the problem is that when you loaded the string in the uri, it is put inside an Object `loaderInfo.parameters` so if you want to pass those parameters, you need to create a string to pass these into.

here's a script from http://ragona.com/blog/pass-flashvars-loaded-swf/ that shows how to convert that into a string array again

```
//:: Store loader info
var lInfo:Object = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;
//:: Flashvars
var fVars:String = "?whee=nada"; //:: Getting the syntax change (? --> &) out of the way with a dummy var

//:: Set path + data
for (var flashVar in lInfo)
{
    fVars += "&" + flashVar + "=" + lInfo[flashVar];
}

var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(String("/myPath.swf" + fVars));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention, I have tried that too and it gives the same error.

I saw a page mentioned because passing FlashVars cannot work with local swf, is that the problem?

Comment: I see no reason for that not working, but you can try "sandboxing" the permissions for the folder it is in.

Answer (score 0):

How do I sandbox the permissions? I tried adding the folder via the settings, but that didn't work too.

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502

I made a simple as new project. This is the complete code.

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip ();

var loader:Loader = new Loader ();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, OnComplete);

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("B.swf"); 

var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
variables.xml = "test2.xml"; 

// This line causes the error 2044, if i comment out, it runs fine without FlashVars   
request.data = variables; 

loader.load (request);  


function OnComplete (e:Event)
{
    trace ("On Complete");
    mc = e.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
    addChild (mc);
}
```

Comment: I found what's the problem. It works if I run the swf in the normal flash player, but not the debug version when I launch from editor with Ctrl+Enter. But I cannot debug anymore hmmm..

Comment: trace (Security.sandboxType), gives me localTrusted. I added Security.allowInsecureDomain("*") but still no go.