# flashvars help, dymanically load an XML file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flashvars

Hay, i have a flash movie which loads a static XML file, the script for this looks like

```
list = "list.xml";
var listXml:XML = new XML();
listXml.ignoreWhite = true;
listXml.load(list);
```

I want to be able to change this 'list' variable dynamically, perhaps using flashVars.

like this

```
 var flashvars = {
    xmlpath: "list.xml"
};
```

Any idea's how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=185370

[AS3 Pass FlashVars to loaded swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302722/as3-pass-flashvars-to-loaded-swf)

if you have some code already, please share, so we could advice you

Answer (score 0):

The flashvars properties are accessible in the parameters property of the LoaderInfo object.

```
In your main class:

var info:Object = this.loader.contentLoaderInfo.parameters;
var xmlpath:String = info.xmlpath;
```

Check this article:
http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html