# passing Data from parent to Child in actionScript3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two swf, A.swf and B.swf: B.swf is a child of A.swf.i want to access the variable of a.swf in b.swf.Is it Possible?How Can i do this?
please Explain With Example.
Thanks in Advance

```
loader.load(new URLrequest"b.swf"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded)
function swfLoaded(e:Event):void
{
 data= e.target.content;    //data is the String  i declared outside                
 mainContainer.addChild(loader);In this Loader i want to dispaly the data
}
```

Comment: u have commented `//data is the String  i declared outside`.. nope..it will have the loaded swf contents.

Comment: ok Benny how to pass the Variable into B.swf From a.swf?

Comment: Just Imagine ur b.swf containes public var chk:String = "benny";
then u can access the chk var from a.swf...like this 
`data.chk = "geo";`

Comment: But Benny Am getting the variable  chk:String = "benny" in a.swf only But i want to pass it in B.swf.

Comment: I have passed the string "geo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, possible.

```
var myObj:Object = new Object();
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();

var swfFile:URLRequest=new URLRequest("b.swf");
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadedHandler);
swfLoader.load(swfFile);

private function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
    myObj = e.target.content;
    //trace(myObj.mcBanner.prevImage);
}
```

Now myObj var containes the loaded SWF contents. U can access easily.

Comment: am trying with String,But it Displays null Value Benny

Comment: What u want to access from  b.swf?

Comment: No i want to access from a.swf and pass it into  b.swf

Comment: U didn't get me... Whether u want to access a var or function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4880/discussion-between-leema-rose-and-benny-geo)

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is the document Class in b.swf:

```
public Class B extends MovieClip {
   protected var _theVar:String;
   public function get theVar():String {
      return _theVar;
   }
   public function set theVar(value:String):void {
      if (value != _theVar) {
         _theVar=value;
         //do something here with the new value
      }
   }
   public function B () {
      super();
   }
}
```

in a's document Class:

```
//this will be inside a function that detects that the content has been loaded
var bContent = yourLoader.loaderInfo.content as B;
bContent.theVar = 'some value';
```

Comment: -1 because this will compile class B into class A.
This is REALLY bad practice.

Comment: It really depends on how much is actually in Class B (the as).  It's not going to compile the symbol information from the timeline.  IMO, users asking such questions are not ready for Interfaces.

Comment: I understand, but still... Teach a man how to fish...
And since they're not using interfaces, it's not only the document class that gets compiled in, but everything it depends on, which (when not using interfaces) tends to be 100% of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass a value to the loaded swf you can use the parameters object, see
[AS3 Pass FlashVars to loaded swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302722/as3-pass-flashvars-to-loaded-swf)

Comment: i saw that link sir Multiple markers at this line:
-1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: URLVariables.
-1180: Call to a possibly undefined method URLVariables.i got error

Comment: Ummm, you shouldn't be copying the question, but the answer.