# Sending information Main swf to loaded in swf

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have already properly loaded in a swf in my main fla file. The swf I am loading in has interactions and has it's own code level. The swf loaded in uses some XML to run different objects. I want to pass the file path of xml from my main FLA file down to the loaded in swf.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Are you running in browser or in air? And which application domain did you use on the loaded swf?

Comment: Running in a browser. I believe we just used the current Domain for the application domain.

Comment: Have you seen this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302722/as3-pass-flashvars-to-loaded-swf

Comment: I had not seen that, but I am using 10.1. It would probably be a major pain in the but to switch to 10.2. we have hundreds of flash files currently in 10.1.

And just for the record, I did try that in 10.1 and it's not in the api.