# How can I pass FlashVars to the swf loaded by Loader.loadBytes?

Tags: actionscript-3, loader, flashvars

When I load it by `Loader.load` I can pass them via `URLRequest`. But I don't see any opportunity in case of `Loader.loadBytes`.
This question is similar to [Passing flashvars-style parameters to a loaded SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407858).

Comment: Do you have to use FlashVars? Why not just have it implement an Interface and call a method or something on it?

Comment: Yes, I have. I haven't access to loaded swf.

Comment: Why not? Is the loaderInfo.content empty after the complete event fires?

Comment: I mean I haven't access to its source code to "implement an Interface and call a method or something on it". What do you mean by " Is the loaderInfo.content empty after the complete event fires?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in API documentation. I've been hinted at another site.

You should use [`parameters`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#parameters) property of `LoaderContext` object which you pass to the [`Loader.loadBytes`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29) method. But it works only for the AS3 swfs. It seems to be imporsible for the AS1/2 swfs.

```
var swf:ByteArray = getSWF();//swf bytes from nowhere
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.parameters = {a: "1", b: "2"};
loader.loadBytes(swf, loaderContext);
```

I think it's right answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Great! runs for me only if parameters are strings:

```
loaderContext.parameters = {"a": "1", "b": "2"};
```